# IE8 and CSS rendering issue

Tags: css

I have a website that renders a calendar-like presentation that is set out using css.  It took a while to get the rendering just right.  In fact, different browsers require a unique css.  I am having difficulty now with IE8 (as well as Opera9) in that the presentation does not take up the full screen width.  I would appreciate advice.

the URL is www.firstport.com

The css is as follows:

```
html,
 body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: hidden;
    }



td {height:13.6%;}


.sectionhead {
text-align: left;
background: #EBEBEB;
height: 99.5%;
width: 98%;
border-style:ridge;
border-width:thin;
border-color:grey;
float: left;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
overflow-y: auto;
color: black;

}

.sectionhead a {

color: black;
background: #EBEBEB;
font-weight: normal;
margin-left:2px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.SubHeaderLink a {

color: #006633;
text-decoration:none;
background: #EBEBEB;
}

.SubHeaderLink a:hover {

color:  blue;
background: #EBEBEB;
text-decoration:underline;
}

.popuplink a {

color: blue;
background: #EBEBEB;
font-weight: normal;
margin-left:2px;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you post the corresponding HTML too.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML has an error in the `<table>` tag here:

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 height="97% width="100%" cols=5>
```

It's missing a closing quote. Change it to:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="97%" width="100%" cols="5">
```

And IE8 will render correctly.

P.S. Please, please, please quote (`""`) all of your attribute values.

Comment: Thank you.  The correction solved the width rendering issue in both IE8 and Opera 9.  I have a follow-up question re Opera, which I will post.